# Test content of a custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building an iOS application with Swift 2 that uses custom table view cells, with additional labels, image views, etc. (let's call the class `CustomTableViewCell`). I've made the class-storyboard connections to every subview and assigned an identifier to the cell. I've mocked the data and tried to run the application to check that the cell is properly mapped, and it looks ok.

The problem is that I cannot treat a dequeued cell as a `CustomTableViewCell` to test the value of its properties. When I downcast the cell returned from `tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)` all custom property values turns into `nil` and my tests fail.

Here's my code:

MyViewControllerTests.swift

```
  func testShouldConfigureTableViewCellToDisplayNotification() {
    // Given
    sut.tableView = TableViewSpy()

    let items = [ <some items to display> ]
    sut.displayedItems = items

    // When
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    let cell = viewController.tableView(viewController.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Then
    XCTAssertEqual(cell.detailLabel?.text, "foo", "A properly configured table view cell should display the notification detail")
    XCTAssertEqual(cell.titleLabel?.text, "Bar", "A properly configured table view cell should display the notification title")
    XCTAssertEqual(cell.dateLabel?.text, "15/04/2016", "A properly configured table view cell should display the notification date")
  }
```

MyViewController.swift

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CustomTableViewCell"
    let displayedItem = displayedItems[indexPath.row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CustomTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
      cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.dateLabel?.text = displayedItem.date
    cell!.detailLabel?.text = displayedItem.detail
    cell!.titleLabel?.text = displayedItem.title
    return cell!
  }
```

CustomTableViewCell.swift

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  // MARK: Properties
  @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!  

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code
  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

      // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CustomTableViewCell"
    let displayedItem = displayedItems[indexPath.row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CustomTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
      cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.dateLabel?.text = displayedItem.date
    cell!.detailLabel?.text = displayedItem.detail
    cell!.titleLabel?.text = displayedItem.title
    return cell!
  }
```

with

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CustomTableViewCell"
    let displayedItem = displayedItems[indexPath.row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.dateLabel.text = displayedItem.date
    cell.detailLabel.text = displayedItem.detail
    cell.titleLabel.text = displayedItem.title
    return cell
  }
```

If you have connected your cell correctly ins storyboard then this should work. Otherwise check that you have correctly assigned all IBOutlets for your cell.

If something doesn't work please check the following:

1) Select your cell in the storyboard.

2) In the right column open Identity Inspector (3rd tab at the top). Make sure that the class of your cell is set to `CustomTableViewCell`.

3) In the Attributes Inspector (4th tab) make sure that cell identifier is correctly spelled.

4) In Connections inspector (last tab) assign all of the IBOutlets of your cell which you have defined.

Comment: This makes XCode to throw some build errors: `Cannot force unwrap value of non optional type "CustomTableViewCell"`, because I've unwrapped it when the cell was dequeued. When I delete all those unwraps from the properties binding I get a fatal error when running the test: `"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

Comment: my bad! Check update answer. The problem was with usage of "cell!" after the dequeuing of the cell :)

Comment: This means that you did not correctly specify your cell in the storyboard. I will now update my answer by providing what else you need to check

Comment: I've tried to re-assign the outlets, look for typos in my identifiers and re-assign the CustomTableViewCell class to my cell, and I keep getting the unwrapping optional error. An important detail is that I'm getting this issue only when I try to unit test using the cell from `cellForRow:atIndexPath` as a CustomTableViewCell, but when I run the app, tge values are properly mapped

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample looks like you didn't registered your cell for reusing.

```
tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

Comment: As far as I know, I should register that class if I don't use storyboard for cell-class mapping. Are these techniques complementary?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right. You don't need to use this code if you are using prototype cells. In this case it's enough to ensure that you added correct cell identifier in IB.
Also in general you need to use this method to get UITableView cell
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
But you directly called delegate method which can return empty cell if your table not displayed. I can only suggest to try to set breakpoints in UITableView delegate methods to understand what happens wrong. Or post sample project with your VC code.

Comment: I've tried what you pointed out, and got to the conclusion that my test is failing when I try to downcast the result of `cellForRow:atIndexPath`.